# Why is the '>' combinator not working as I expect it too? I have to style elements separately that I thought could be styled together

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's the fiddle followed by the code. http://jsfiddle.net/ogr27cLa/4/

```
<div>
<ul id="navigation">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><li>
        <p>one</p>
        <ul>
            <a href="http://www.bing.com"><li>
                <p>one</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>two</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>three</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>four</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>five</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>six</p>
            </li></a>
        </ul>
    </li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>
        <p>two</p>
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>one</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>two</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>three</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>four</p>
            </li></a>
        </ul>
    </li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>
        <p>three</p>
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>one</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>two</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>three</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>four</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>five</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>six</p>
            </li></a>
        </ul>
    </li></a>
    <li>
        <p>four</p>
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>one</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>two</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>three</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>four</p>
            </li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>
                <p>five</p>
            </li></a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <a href="#"><li>
        <p>five</p>
    </li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>
        <p>six</p>
    </li></a>
</ul>
```

```
/* basic overrides for user agent */
html, body, ul, li, p, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* This div is going to stretch the width of the body */
div {
    width: 100%;
    background: #00f; /* replace with background image */
}
/* navigation is a list of buttons */
ul#navigation {
    margin: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 957px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
/* all paragraph elements in the nav */
ul#navigation p {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
}
/* all anchor tags in the nav */
ul#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
/* non-nested nav buttons */
ul#navigation>li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #00f; /* replace with background image */
}
/* hover behavior for non-nested nav buttons */
ul#navigation>li:hover {
    background: #55f; /* replace with background image */
}
/* non-nested nav buttons with no nested nav */
ul#navigation>a li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #00f; /* replace with background image */
}
/* hover behavior for non-nested nav buttons with no nested nav */
ul#navigation>a li:hover {
    background: #55f; /* replace with background image */
}
/* behavior for when you hover over the non-nested nav buttons that styles the nested nav */
ul#navigation li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
/* nested nav */
ul#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
/* all nav buttons */
ul#navigation li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 159px;
}
/* nested nav buttons */
ul#navigation li li {
    background: #00f;
}
/* behavior for hovering over a nested nav button */
ul#navigation li li:hover {
    background: #aaf;
}
/* behavior for when you hover over the nested nav buttons that styles the nested paragraph tag */
ul#navigation li li:hover p {
    color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Basically, why do I have to use *ul#navigation>a li* to style the nav buttons that don't have a nested ul and *ul#navigation>li* to style the ones that have a nested ul?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, your HTML is invalid a list item element (i.e. `li`) is the only valid child of a list element (`ul`), you should not put any other elements directly within your `ul`

That aside, the `>` selector relates to immediate [**direct children of an element.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are
>   combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector
>   expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for
>   which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector,
>   regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. I'm self taught so sometimes the basics escape me. Here's the new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ivanjsfiddle00/7y03mezs/